# Data flow parallel sending to webserver and receiving

Tags: c#, tcp

Im searching for way to send packets parallel from proxies. Is that possible ? to split data flow throw multiple proxies as parralel flow and on the target site merge that packets ? Same with geting packets from server.

```
Example: sentence: owl does hoot

proxy1 -> owl -> send to -> site.com
proxy2 -> does -> send to -> site.com
proxy3 -> hoot -> send to -> site.com

on the end merge to -> owl does hoot (act as one host)
```

While i want to receive data get request same way but split receiving to proxies not only one.

Is that possible ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how you  could accept the several data streams :

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
        string IPAddr = "127.0.0.1";
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(new IPAddress(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(IPAddr)), 8080);
        listener.Start();
        while (true) {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => handleTCPResults(listener.AcceptTcpClient()));
        } 

    }

    static void handleTCPResults(TcpClient client) {
        var stream = client.GetStream();
    }
```

You could save the data somehow and then you have put everything together. My first thought would be to get the first two bytes ( or more if you need higher numbers ) of the Stream and let the first byte for example be the number of the 
merged packed  , the second byte the index of the package. Then you have to find the best way for you to get the data together.

```
byte numberOfSplitPackage = Convert.ToByte(stream.ReadByte());
byte IndexOfPackage = Convert.ToByte(stream.ReadByte());
```

save in List of somthing like this:

```
public struct Package {
    public byte numberOfSplitPackage;
    public byte IndexOfPackage;
    public byte[] body;
   }
```